# HTML - Cannot set property 'src' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code, I am trying to do an animation with 8 pictures, I was thinking first that the error is because the images are .jpg, but i tryed even converting them to .gif format and the code still did not work, When I try to run the code, i get an error saying: "Cannot set property 'src' of undefined", I don't see any mistakes in the code, i tryed looking at it multiple times, please if someone can help, thanks.
    
    
    
            G:\Year 2\OOD - object oriented development\Webpages\Assignment\Explosion

```
    <script>


    var explosion = new Array(8);
    var c = 0;
    var startExplode;
    var i = 0;




        explosion[0] = 'ex1.jpg'
        explosion[1] = "ex2.jpg"
        explosion[2] = "ex3.jpg"
        explosion[3] = "ex4.jpg"
        explosion[4] = "ex5.jpg"
        explosion[5] = "ex6.jpg"
        explosion[6] = "ex7.jpg"
        explosion[7] = "ex8.jpg"



function explode()
{   
    if(c == 7 | (i > 0 & i <= 1))
    {
        c = 0;
    }   
    else
    {
        c++;
        document.animation.src = explosion[c];  
    }
}


</script>
<body>
<form>
<img src ="ex1.jpg" name = "explosion" position = "fixed">

<input type="button" name="startExplode" value="explode"
    onClick="startExplode=setInterval('explode()',20);">

</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There is no `document.animation` ?

Comment: Interesting of you to use `new Array()`.

Comment: Have you got an solution for it James? I tryed a lot but haven't got the right answer yet, even I do have a similar code like this but still cant get it to work, even if i compared both codes and there are no differences between.

Comment: I solved it by chaning .explosion to animation, but I don't get why does this line matter? :O , <img src ="ex1.jpg" name = "explosion" position = "fixed">

Comment: It's seems that you are really confused on what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with the code:

In the function, the AND and OR operators are doubled, not singles:

```
if(c == 7 | (i > 0 & i <= 1))
```

SHOULD BE:

```
if(c == 7 || (i > 0 && i <= 1))
```

NEXT, you are not referring to the image tag properly, so the SRC will not update, in addition, the image is call "explosion", not "animation", at least in your HTML.  Also, if you give the image tag an ID, you can refer to the ID (much easier).

So the code:

```
document.animation.src = explosion[c];  

<img src ="ex1.jpg" name = "explosion" position = "fixed">
```

SHOULD BE:

```
document.getElementById("explosion").src=explosion[c];

<img src="ex1.jpg" name="animation" position="fixed" id="explosion">
```

I hope this helps!